# How to import multiple components with the same name in a Vuejs project?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've inherited a Vue.js project that, among other things, has this:

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

<multiselect :multiple="true"
   v-model="selectedTags"
   :options="tagOptions"
   label="title"
   track-by="id"></multiselect>
```

Now, on the same page, we are also supposed to have a different multiselect object, imported from a different place, that looks like:

```
import Multiselect from './../../../../../../vendor/devcompany/scripts/vue/components/form/multiselect.vue';

<multiselect v-model="selectedTeacherIds"
   :sortable="true"
   :options="computedTeacherOptions">
   <template slot="selected-option-value" slot-scope="{optionKey}">
      {{teacherNames[optionKey]}}
   </template>
```

Each of these works well individually, but I am supposed to somehow import both of them and use them both within the same component. Clearly this will not work without some sort of alteration to the code.

Is there some syntax to, perhaps, `import as` and thus change the name of one of the objects? Or do I need to go into the source code of one of them and change the naming there? The former (or some other solution not requiring changing the multiselect core files themselves) would be more desirable.

EDIT: This is what the code looks like more broadly.

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

import BbcodeEditor from './../elements/bbcode-editor';

import ApiVideoSelect from './api-video-select';

/* import other assets */

export default {

    components: {ApiVideoClassDetail, ApiProgramCard, ApiUploader, Multiselect, Draggable, Datepicker, BbcodeEditor, ApiVideoSelect},
```

So I am wondering how to edit this syntax to add the other multiselect under a different name. I don't see how this could work:

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';
import Multiselect from './../../../../../../vendor/frismedia/scripts/vue/components/form/multiselect.vue';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not have to change core files, just change the name while using the component:

```
import Multiselect from '....vue/components/form/multiselect.vue';

// your parent component
export default {
     components: {
         'my-custom-multiselect' : Multiselect 
     }
}

// in template:
<my-custom-multiselect> </my-custom-multiselect>
```

---

**A simpler syntax:**  Change the name while importing

```
import MyCustomMultiselect from '....vue/components/form/multiselect.vue';

export default {
     components: {
          MyCustomMultiselect
     }
}

// in template:
<my-custom-multiselect> </my-custom-multiselect>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the renaming in the components object and inside the template, but please see the edit at the bottom of my question for what's troubling me.